# Regular Expression - I want to replace some sentence

Tags: java, regex

I tried many times to replace some text using regular expressions but it's not easy for me.
The problem is '</b>'. I don't need this tag. 
Please, check my code.

My language is Java. You can check my regex at http://regexr.com?3849s

```
(?<=(count))(.*?)(?=(ea)*\s*<br>\s*(<b>|<b\s))
```

source1.

```
..... <b>count : </b>&nbsp;2,020ea + 234ea + 22ea + 33ea <br>   <b>....
```

source2.

```
..... <br>count :  &nbsp;2,020 ea <br>   <b style="tt"> ......
```

Correct Answer

```
source1: &nbsp;2,020ea + 234ea + 22ea + 33 <br>
source2: &nbsp;2,020 <br>
```

Comment: What language is this? JavaScript? PHP? Please include the tag of the language you're trying to do this in.

Comment: its java. :) but i checking my code at regexr.com.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply that you're replacing your `<` with `&lt;` in your regexr for some reason. If I try it with just the `<` as normal characters, it does work [just fine](http://regex101.com/r/tM7dM3).

Comment: THNX reply. but &lt; problem is made by regexr.com. I wrote my code right way. 

The Point of my problem is </b> tag. :) Can U check my code again, plz?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
The key point is it's impossible to remove '</b>' at one swoop.
So I did apply a regular expression again for removing '</b>' to the first result.